# 9-slice scaling/stretching in the background, using Cocoa on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I want to stretch an image using "9-slice" scaling, where only the centre of the image is scaled. Exactly like UIImage's[`stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:) method, however I want to do this in a background thread. I understand that this method can only be used in the gui thread.

I'm developing on iOS / iPad / iPhone.

Does anyone have a code snippet, or know of a library that can do this? I'm trying to not re-invent the wheel!

#### Some related references I've found useful:

CGContext docs:

- http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html

Nice blog entry on drawing in the background:

- http://joris.kluivers.nl/iphone-dev/?p=BackgroundImageProcessing

Rotating an image using CGContext:

- http://blog.coriolis.ch/2009/09/04/arbitrary-rotation-of-a-cgimage/

Answer (score 3):

Since iOS 4, some parts of UIKit are thread-safe; I believe UIGraphics functions and UIImage drawing should work.

If you need to support iOS 3, then it's a bit more difficult. If you want to avoid UIKit entirely (possibly wise), then you'll need to pass the background thread a CGImageRef. There are additional things you might need to worry about; I'm assuming `scale` is 1 and `imageOrientation` is portrait.

1. Create a context: `CGBitmapContextCreate()`
2. Create your sub-images: `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect()`.
3. Draw each sub-image to the right place: `CGContextDrawImage()`
4. Get the image from the context: `CGBitmapContextCreateImage()`
5. Release the necessary things and return the CGImageRef to the main thread.
6. In the main thread, use `+[UIImage imageWithCGImage:]` or `+imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:` (note that in the latter case, images with scale 2 only seem to support portrait orientations; I'm not sure why).

Also note that it's significantly better to stick the image in a UIImageView and set contentStretch appropriately, since then the scaling is done on the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

AppKit has a nice `NSDrawNinePartImage()` function. I found this code online and it provides similar functionality for iOS.

http://pastie.org/1147077/

```
//
//  UIImageAdditions.m
//  Newspress
//
//  Created by Kyle Van Essen on 10-04-10.
//  Copyright 2010 Vibealicious. All rights reserved.
//

#import "UIImageAdditions.h"


@implementation UIImage (Additions)

+(void)drawNinePartImage:(NSArray *)images inRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGPoint origin = rect.origin;
    CGSize size = rect.size;

    NSInteger partCount = 9;

    if ([images count] < partCount)
        return;

    CGRect rects[partCount];
    UIImage *image;

    // Top Row
    image = [images objectAtIndex:0];
    rects[0] = CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    image = [images objectAtIndex:2];
    rects[2] = CGRectMake(origin.x + size.width - image.size.width, origin.y, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    image = [images objectAtIndex:1];
    rects[1] = CGRectMake(rects[0].size.width + rects[0].origin.x, origin.y, size.width - rects[0].size.width - rects[2].size.width, image.size.height);

    // Bottom Row
    image = [images objectAtIndex:6];
    rects[6] = CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y + size.height - image.size.height, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    image = [images objectAtIndex:8];
    rects[8] = CGRectMake(origin.x + size.width - image.size.width, origin.y + size.height - image.size.height, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    image = [images objectAtIndex:7];
    rects[7] = CGRectMake(rects[6].size.width + rects[6].origin.x, origin.y + size.height - image.size.height, size.width - rects[6].size.width - rects[8].size.width, image.size.height);

    // Middle Row
    image = [images objectAtIndex:3];
    rects[3] = CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y + rects[0].size.height, image.size.width, size.height - rects[0].size.height - rects[6].size.height);

    image = [images objectAtIndex:5];
    rects[5] = CGRectMake(origin.x + size.width - image.size.width, origin.y + rects[0].size.height, image.size.width, size.height - rects[2].size.height - rects[8].size.height);

    image = [images objectAtIndex:4];
    rects[4] = CGRectMake(rects[3].size.width + rects[3].origin.x, origin.y + rects[0].size.height, size.width - rects[0].size.width - rects[2].size.width, size.height - rects[1].size.height - rects[7].size.height);

    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < partCount; index++)
    {               
        UIColor *pattern = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[images objectAtIndex:index]];

        //NSLog(@"Frame: %f, %f, %f, %f", rects[index].origin.x, rects[index].origin.y, rects[index].size.width, rects[index].size.height);

        [pattern set];
        CGContextSetPatternPhase(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGSizeMake(rects[index].origin.x, rects[index].origin.y));
        UIRectFill(rects[index]);

        [pattern release];
    }

    [[UIColor clearColor] set];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks Alexsander. Good starting point! This answer needs an image already split into 9 sections, rather than stretching a single image. I'll still need to find / write a splitter.

Comment: Unfortunately the snippet also uses UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() which should only be called from the main thread.